# Analytics Google API Error 403: "User does not have any Google Analytics Account"

Tags: error-handling, google-analytics

I'm creating an script, based on Google Analytics step-by-step guide from this page:

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api

Authorization is done without problems, until it tries to access data. The return code is 403, and error message is:

> User does not have any Google Analytics account

This message has no sense: my account has google analytics data, tracking multiple websites, and I can access it from web browser without problem. I've allowed Analytics API through Google APIs console, and API access is giving me right data.

Answer (score 353):

I had this problem too. I fixed it by adding the email address for my service account to the Google Analytics profile I wanted it to access.

I got the email address (something like xxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com) for the service account by looking under the "API Access" tab in the Google APIs console.

Then, I followed [Google's instructions for adding an email address to an Analytics profile](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009702). Now everything's working as expected.

Good luck!

Comment: This is the best answer, I tried it and it works like charm!!
Thanks a lot @Sebastian!

Comment: if you have more than one profile in your account and you want to access their data using GA API should you keep adding the xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com to the Analytics profile, or there is a more efficient way without involving a manual way. Thanks!

Comment: @mongotop you're welcome! Unfortunately I don't know a more efficient way of doing this - let us know in the comments if you find one.

Comment: If you add the user at Property level make sure to add it to the proper view, as the Analytics UI is sometimes misleading

Comment: @SebastianMotraghi I found a way to access Google Account data without having to add the service account as a Google Analytics user.  See my answer below.

Comment: I also had set developer email to analytics account,
Still i get this error,
User does not have any Google Analytics account

Comment: Ok got it, You must have login to use this.

Comment: I have an account with 690 profiles, each profile having up to 10 properties... And I need to build a console app with access to all these accounts. How can I do this?...

Comment: @SsjCosty sorry, I have no idea – it's been over two years since I last dealt with Google Analytics.

Comment: You're a legend, I've spent the entire day trying to set this up.

Comment: To find the service email address visit https://console.developers.google.com, click "credentials" in the left sidebar, click "manage service accounts" at the bottom. It's in column "Service account ID".

Comment: Man big thank youuu, you're the real man! Why is this NOT CLEARLY MENTIONED by Google in their API Docs, till 2019 now!!!

Comment: Just thought I would add this answer still worked in 2020

Answer (score 91):

Just add you given email (format of `71667655853644-o653rrdkq5hthsgo0otbpojoo@developer.gserviceaccount.com`)

to User Managers:

[image: User does not have any Google Analytics account]

Wish it helps you

Comment: Sadly the error did not go away. Still Message: GAPI: Failed to request account data. Error: "{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have any Google Analytics account."}],"code":403,"message":"User does not have any Google Analytics account."}}"

Comment: @Lev over 3 years this answer is still valid. I just hoped Google improved it, but no. It was done perfectly :D

Comment: @IriYork after 5 years

Answer (score 30):

I was facing the same issue. It got resolved by adding the email id of the service account user(`your account@yourwebsite-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com`), to the users in your Analytics account under-

**Analytics-Home Page ->Admin(left pane) -> User Management -> add (click on plus sign on right side of the menu) -> Add new User -> Add the email id in enter email addresses.**

[image]

Now, this will solve the issue.

Comment: Why this answer is not accepted ? I spend 2 days try to find out why following the tutorial leading me to this error.

Answer (score 10):

It is mentioned in a comment above but if you add the email address under the User Management for your *account*, it won't work. You have to click on the User Management under the *view* part of the screen.

[image]

Comment: I know many years have passed, but I now added the address to the *account*, and it looks like it works nicely.

Comment: i can't see the `User Management` link under View on my end

Answer (score 7):

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Copy email address in "Service Account".

[image]

Open Google Analytics, add email above as a new user.

Answer (score 6):

This message we get when no permission granted to `client_email`, in the [google alalytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics), `client_email` is you got [from the JSON file](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). to grant permission to `client_email` you're using in your App, Head over to [Google Analytics site](https://analytics.google.com/analytics) and click "Admin (setting icon)"

[image]

## you'll get menu list right, there click on "View User Management"

[image]

## There you'll see "+" icon, and "add user",

[image]

## once you click on that, you need to add `client_email` in the "email address field" and save it, you should be good to go!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will also get this error if you have never logged in with the google account youre trying to authenticate with.

Comment: I'll just leave this here: Link to the [Google Analytics web interface](https://www.google.com/analytics/web)

Comment: And where is password for email? I tried password that google shows me before downloading .p12 certificate but it is not valid

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the 403 error until I changed the permissions of the email account from inside Google Analytics from 'Read & Analyze' to something else, saved it, and then changed the permissions back to 'Read & Analyze' and it worked.

Comment: This helped.  I created a new "Service Account" under APIs & Auth/Credentials; and saved the .p12 key pair.  I then went into the Analytics user management console, and added the Service User's email address.  .p12 authorization using the PHP API works, but only if I check off "Read & Analyze" *only* in the permissions list.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if that doesn't work, Try to open your JSON file which you have downloaded and Search for `client_email` and copy that email address and add it to the View File

Click On

```
Analytics-Home Page ->Admin(left pane) -> User Management -> add (click on plus sign on right side of the menu) -> Add new User -> Add the client_email address which you copied.
```

If that still doesn't work

```
Analytics-Homepage-> Admin ->Views->User Management(Click on add(+) symbol, add this ccopied client_email address and give permissions and save it.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting the 403 error.  These steps got me around it.  To be clear, I was trying to get Google's sample "HelloAnalytics.php" working with OAuth (sans user interaction, suitable for cron job etc).

After enabling the Analytics API, I created a new "Service Account" under APIs & Auth/Credentials; and saved the .p12 key pair.  I then went into the Analytics user management console, and added that Service User's email address.

.p12 authorization using the PHP API works if I check off *only* "Read & Analyze" *only* in the permissions list. If I add "Manage Users" and/or "Edit", I get the 403.     Hope this is helpful, I was grinding on this for a couple of hours...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and I found that the problem was that I had asked for too many permissions.  The Developer Console says to ask for both `http://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics` *and* `http://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly` permissions.  This did not work when I was also using the `sub` claim.  A `sub` claim instructs Google to issue an access token that operates *on behalf of another user* — in my case the Google account that owns the service account. I removed the `analytics` permission and stuck with `analytics.readonly` with the sub claim:

```
{
  "iss":"123123123123123-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub":"me.example@gmail.com"
  "scope":"http://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics",
  ...
}
```

The Bearer token issued allows me to make (at least some) Google Analytics queries to profiles that are owned by completely different Google accounts, but that have been shared (read-only) with my gmail user (me.example@gmail.com).

Comment: What is sub when I am using Google Analytics client SDK?

Comment: I wish this worked! I'm getting the following error when I try doing the same: Google_Auth_Exception [ 401 ]:
Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }'

Comment: I suggest you keep at it. We still use this to grab real time data from GA every few minutes, all using bash, no less!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by making sure that the

client  = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'X',:application_version => '1')

application name variable 'X above was the ACCOUNT name on the GA dashboard, not the PROPERTY name, which in my case was the actual url of the site I want to access.

Confusing, but thankfully fixed (with no thanks to Google!)

Comment: I am trying to find this 'X'. Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens since we dont provide a "sub" argument. Unless we provide this, the call happens on behalf of that long service account  email.

So just provide a sub argument, with an email which you already have given access in the report and things should work well!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, since I didn't sign in the google analytics. So I had resolved it by signing in the analytics account.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a service account, you can sidestep the need for adding a adding new user permissions (as per the top answers in this thread) by using `OAuth client ID` credentials.

Go to the [API credentials dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and click "Create credentials" -> "OAuth client ID". Afterwards you should get a client ID and a client secret that you'll need to authenticate the API.

Now you can use `OAuth2WebServerFlow` to authenticate on a per-use basis. Here is a python3 example:

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

# TODO: Fill these in...
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''
VIEW_ID = ''

flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
)

authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print('Receive code from:\n%s\n' % authorize_url)
code = input('Enter code here:').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

api = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
body={
    'reportRequests': [{
        'viewId': VIEW_ID,
        'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
        'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
        'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
    }]
}

data = api.reports().batchGet(body=body).execute()
```