# Why we Should add xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com to the user account so we can retrieve our google analytics data?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Following this tutorial step by step https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/tutorials/hello-analytics-api I got this message error "User does not have any Google Analytics Account” . more info are here at [stackoverflow](http://goo.gl/Fdu59) ,
One guys from the community suggested to add the email address the one I use to make the connection with google Analytics API looks similar to xxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com to the profile account following the steps described [here](http://goo.gl/sl5x3)  and that works perfect!

the situation is that my account has access to multiple website analytics data, so I have to go to each client profile, and add the email address if I have the admin access if not I have to contact the client to do so from his side, and that seems like is so much work to do manually.

**Is there's an officiant way to have access to these profiles without adding xxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com to the user account?**

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837748/analytics-google-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-any-google-analytics-account then

Comment: Hi @eis, Thanks for taking a look to my question, that was the research I done before posting the question, and you can see in the thread that I asked the same question but no luck, my question is different because I'm looking for a more officiant way to connect to GA profiles without adding the email address xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com manually, I know the alternative solution which is the manual stuff, but I'm asking the community if someone had the same problem and he figure out how to solve it without involving so much manual.

Comment: I don't think that requesting the client to add two emails, so my gmail and developer email will have access to the analytics reports is efficient. it must be some work around, or I'm missing something really obvious here.