# Accessing google analytics through nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I'm using nodejs, and I would like to display some data from google analytics.

On google API explorer, I've find this url to get my data:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%XXXXX&start-date=2013-08-17&end-date=2013-09-15&metrics=ga%3Avisits&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

However, if I access this url I get:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

How can I pass my login through the url and then access my data ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually putting your API key here? `&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: Yes I did. But seems that I needed token. I use request to call `https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:XXXXX88&metrics=ga:visits&start-date=2013-08-17&end-date=2013-09-15&access_token=XXXXXXXX&access_type_token=bearer` and everything works.

Comment: But when I try to refresh the token, using request on `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_secret=XXX&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=YYYY&client_id=ZZZZ` I get `error, invalid request.`

Answer (score 11):

From the Google API console, you need to activate the Analytics API, and finally setup a Service Account, you'll then download a `*.p12` file.

From this `*.p12` file, you need to convert it to a `*.pem` file, to do that, run the following:

`openssl pkcs12 -in XXXXX.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out XXXXX.pem`

You'll be asked a password, it should be `notasecret`

Now you got the `*.pem` file you need, and the account email is the one displayed in the google api console, as `EMAIL ADDRESS`.

Don't forget to add this address to your analytics account (see: [Analytics Google API Error 403: "User does not have any Google Analytics Account"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837748/analytics-google-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-any-google-analytics-account))

You should be good to go with the following snippet:

```
var googleapis = require('googleapis'),
    JWT = googleapis.auth.JWT,
    analytics = googleapis.analytics('v3');

var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'XXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
var SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = __dirname + '/key.pem';


var authClient = new JWT(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE,
    null,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
);

authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    analytics.data.ga.get({ 
        auth: authClient,
        'ids': 'ga:XXXXXXXX',
        'start-date': '2015-01-19',
        'end-date': '2015-01-19',
        'metrics': 'ga:visits'
    }, function(err, result) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

If you're still stuck, it's worth noting that Google has released a nodejs client library (alpha) here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client

Comment: I finally succeeded, using request.get. But still, I'll have a lookt at this library, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@xavier.seignard I follow your snippet but with modifications because I'm using a json file instead of p12 (code below).
But I have a doubt, I'm developing a restful backend in nodejs.
In this case, isn't it necessary to put the ga.get function inside the app.use() to obtain analytics information for every request that is made?

```
var key = require('filename.json');
var authClient = new JWT(
key.client_email,
null,
key.private_key,
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I have mentioned step by step process for Accessing google analytics through nodejs:

For more details : [How To Use Google Analytics Reporting API With Nodejs](https://www.tutscoder.com/post/use-google-analytics-reporting-api-nodejs)

Install googleapis package

`npm i googleapis`

Import
`const { google } = require('googleapis')`

This is sample scripts for getting total views in last month:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

const scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";

const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(
  process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
  null,
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
  scopes
);
const view_id = "Your_View_ID";

async function getViews(){
  try {
    await jwt.authorize();

    const response = await google.analytics("v3").data.ga.get({
      auth: jwt,
      ids: "ga:" + view_id,
      "start-date": "30daysAgo",
      "end-date": "today",
      metrics: "ga:pageviews",
    });

    console.log(response);

  } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
  }
};`
```