# Trying to Access Google Directory API via p12 throws not authorized error

Tags: python-2.7, google-api-client, google-authentication, google-directory-api, google-python-api

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json
import base64
import httplib2

f = file('tara1-553d334b8702.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    'googleapptara@tara1-167105.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    'tara1-554d335b8702.p12',
    private_key_password='notasecret',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'] 
)

delegated_credentials=credentials.create_delegated('tara.gurung@orgemail.net)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)


DIRECOTORY = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
maxResults=10,orderBy='email').execute()
results = DIRECOTORY.users().list(domain='domainnamehere.net').execute()
users = results.get('users', [])

print users
```

Here ,I am trying to do the **server to server authentication** using the **p12** security file and trying to grab all the users in the domain.

***I have successfully fetched the users list by 3legs authentication,by authorizing from the browswer in the same account***

But this way it's throwing me the following errors.

```
File "testing.py", line 41, in <module>
    results = DIRECOTORY.users().list(domain='domainemailhere.net').execute()
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/scripttesting/virtualenvforGapi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/scripttesting/virtualenvforGapi/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=nepallink.net&alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

**SETUP DONE:**

1. I have a super admin level access in the admin console.
2. I have also added
   the scope via **security>showmore>advance>manageipclient>authorize**
   Added the user id and scope

   **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user**
3. Added the users permission in service console and made a owner.
4. Admin SDK is Enabled

Where exactly am I missing the things. Why does  it says I have no authority to access the resources/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using delegated_credentials. Have you used it??

Change following line:

```
DIRECOTORY = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

to

```
DIRECOTORY = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

Comment: THANKS A ALOT ,CRAZY STUPID ERROR,crated a delegates but didn't use it. Thanks

Comment: I am not a API person, however it is worth taking a look at below links:

[got-403-error-when-connecting-to-google-analytics-with-python-2-7-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674380/got-403-error-when-connecting-to-google-analytics-with-python-2-7-x), [quick guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py
)