# Python Google Analytics OAuth Service Account and 2LO; "sub" parameter and domain wide delegation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-analytics

I've read a few comments in some reports on the use of the `sub` parameter which (this is how i understand it), when passed with the credentials object to google analytics for 2LO with service accounts, can be used to act as a substitute for directly authorizing an account manually through the admin console which I've pictured below.

[image]

[Analytics Google API Error 403: "User does not have any Google Analytics Account"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837748/analytics-google-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-any-google-analytics-account)

Am I wrong in my understanding in thinking that if i passed `'sub': 'superuseremail@account.com'` it would take the place of manually setting account permissions in GA?

More importantly, I was granted access to a Google Analytics account via account permissions (such that I don't have super-user authority, or access to the super user email), and I passed this `sub` parameter using that email. I received the 403 error attempting this route.

Put briefly:

The only way to get access with the service account I'm gleaning is either to have access to the super-user email and managing account permissions by manually adding the service account email or to pass the `sub` parameter with the `credentials` object having a `sub` email that is the correct super-user email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: **No!**, Google Analytics is not a [G-Suite](https://apps.google.com/) product, and **a service account does not have the authority to access another's G-Suite account** without direct authorization.

If you take a close look at the [source code for the method](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/498d0b6871bdb8eb2c9471f051c8d5efab4324de/oauth2client/service_account.py) in question:

```
def create_delegated(self, sub):
    """Create credentials that act as domain-wide delegation of authority.
    Use the ``sub`` parameter as the subject to delegate on behalf of
    that user.
    For example::
      >>> account_sub = 'foo@email.com'
      >>> delegate_creds = creds.create_delegated(account_sub)
    Args:
        sub: string, An email address that this service account will
             act on behalf of (via domain-wide delegation).
    Returns:
        ServiceAccountCredentials, a copy of the current service account
        updated to act on behalf of ``sub``.
    """
    new_kwargs = dict(self._kwargs)
    ...
```

You will see that this service account will act on behalf of the user **via domain-wide delegation**.

Then the answer to your question is "what is
[Domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation#create_a_console_project_with_service_account_credentials)?".

In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access a user's data without any manual authorization on their part. In G-Suite domains, the domain administrator can grant third-party applications with domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority.