# Google Analytics Service Email has insufficient permission (Error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. )

Tags: google-analytics, permissions

I had added service email like explained in this ticket below

[Analytics Google API Error 403: "User does not have any Google Analytics Account"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837748/analytics-google-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-any-google-analytics-account)

Now, service email is recognized but it says that there is no sufficient permission of this user no matter I had check all available permissions (Manage User, Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyse)

I am not sure but as I see, I am not lonely with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I had found the cause of the error.

If you get the error that user has no permission this is a good sign.

You will need only to check `$VIEW_ID` variable. You must enter validly view ID.

When you go to your GA dashboard.

Select your project from **Accounts**, 
then under **Properties & Apps** chose an app and then
**Views** section will appear. There is some numeric code. This is **VIEW ID** 
You need to use that number.